# Как реализовать прослушивание состояния удаленного сервера?

Tags: java, spring, rest

Есть ресурс с которого данные нужно получать в несколько этапов, через REST API. После первого запроса выдается токен, после чего нужно с какой-то периодичностью делать запросы, проверяя, не готовы ли данные.

Загвоздка в том, как реализовать паузы между проверками готовности данных. Пока я не нашел ничего лучше чем `Thread.sleep();`, но решение не очень. С другой стороны, посылать запросы подряд, учитывая, что обработка занимает до 20 минут, и дедосить людей - не хочется.

Для отправки запросов я использую `springframework.web.client.RestTemplate`

Пока вызов выглядит так:

```
private RestClient restClient;

public String get(Phone phone) {
    int counter = 0;
    String status = restClient.getStatus(phone.getActivationId());
    while (!status.contains("STATUS_ACCESS") && counter++ < 500) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        status = restClient.getStatus(phone.getActivationId());
    }
    restClient.setStatus(phone.getActivationId(), DONE);
    return status.contains("STATUS_ACCESS") ? status.split(":")[1] : "ERR";
}
```

Внутри RestClient:

```
private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

public String getStatus(String activationId) {
    String url = ...
    ResponseEntity<String> entity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
    return entity.getBody();
}
```

Может быть есть какой-то подход для работы с `RestTemplate` для таких случаев. А то этот `Thread.sleep` мне кажется выглядит ужасно. Или нет? Как в таких ситуациях обычно делают чтобы без костылей?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хм, если у Вас Spring, то проверку можно оформить как задачу (Task). Есть, знаете ли, в Spring-е такой механизм. Подробнее с примерами вот [тут](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/)

Comment: да использовать Scheduled интересная мысль я и забыл про эту штуку, но как ее еще и остановить бы во время я обычно видел как с ее помощью кеш подтягивали а вот с остановкой пока не нашел. Спасибо за идею!